# Bogart in NodeJS 0.6.10 on Windows Fails to start with message about 'sys' module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been learning how to use Bogart (v 0.3.38) under NodeJS (Windows, v 0.6.10), but I can't even get the basic "hello world!" to work, even though I think it must be a problem with the runtime and Bogart.

I'm using the example listed [here](https://github.com/nrstott/bogart) just try to make it run. At the beginning, I got this message:

> The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.

Then I went through all the files in the folder I'm creating the app and change "sys" to "util" in the require statement, and that, for while, got ride of the message above, but then I started getting a message that said that bogart could not access the **isRouter** property of **undefined**, that's when I decided to use the "Hello World" example to see if I was doing something wrong.

Now I get the "sys to util" message mentioned above, a message about the server starting on port 8080 and then a stacktrace:

```
The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
Server running on port 8080

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:646:11)
    at Array.0 (net.js:732:28)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Any clues of what might be wrong here?

As always, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: I had another application running on the same default port (8080) of Bogart, changed the port and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an error of mysql2 connection after update of MySQL config.